# I want to extend my program so that it displays if the user guessed the correct number, guessed too high or too low. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: python-3.x, numbers, dice

```py
def dice_game():
    print ("Welcome to my dice game")
import random
your_name = input ("Please enter your name:")
your_lucky_number = int(input ("Please select a lucky number between 1 and 6:"))
print (your_name,"'s lucky number was:", your_lucky_number)
#initialize computer number
computer_die_roll = random.randint(1,6)
print ("The computer rolled: ", computer_die_roll)

if your_lucky_number == computer_die_roll:
    print("You guessed correct, well done!")
    break
elif your_lucky_number < computer_die_roll:
    print("You guessed too low!")
    else:
        print("You guessed too high!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, roughly in order of severity:

- The indentation of the `else` block is wrong. Dedent it so that it's on the same level as the `if` and `elif` statements.
- You can't use `break` inside an `if` block. This creates a `SyntaxError` so remove it.
- You don't verify your number input and blindly cast it to `int` which breaks when you enter anything that isn't an integer by throwing a `ValueError`.
- Your code looks quite messy. Please follow the [standard formatting conventions](https://pep8.org/). There's a tool to automatically fix this, called `autopep8`.